# How can I to count files are which contains a specific artist?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I get data from document folder. I have several `UITableViewController`. When I move from artist `UITableViewController` to songs `UITableViewController` I want that shows only songs of specific artist. I made it but I get some empty rows. I think that because I count all array of mp3 files. How can I to count files are which contains a specific artist?

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1 ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return contentArray.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("artistTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SongsCellArtist

        var data = contentArray[indexPath.row]
        var documentFolder = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
        var urlForPlayer: NSURL!

        if var urlFromFolder: NSURL = documentFolder.first as? NSURL {
            urlForPlayer = urlFromFolder.URLByAppendingPathComponent(data)
        }
        println(urlForPlayer)

        var player = AVPlayerItem(URL: urlForPlayer)
        var nameSong: String!
        var nameAlbum: String!
        var nameArtistForCell: String!
        var dataForImage: NSData!

        var commonMetaData = player.asset.commonMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem]
        for item in commonMetaData {
            if item.commonKey == "title" {
                nameSong = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey == "album" {
                nameAlbum = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey == "artist" {
                nameArtistForCell = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey == "artwork" {
                dataForImage = item.dataValue
            }
        }

        var arrayFromCell: [String]!
        if nameArtistForCell == nameArtist {
        cell.nameSong?.text = nameSong

        if nameAlbum != nil {
            cell.artistAlbumName?.text = "\(nameArtistForCell) - \(nameAlbum)"
        } else {
            cell.artistAlbumName?.text = "\(nameArtistForCell)"
        }

        if dataForImage != nil {
            cell.imageSongs?.image = UIImage(data: dataForImage)

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing all this work inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Create a function that does the lookup and filtering before you show anything in the table view.  That function should create a very simple array where each object in it matches a cell you really want to display.

At that point, `numberOfRowsInSection` returns the count of that array and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` **only** needs to find the object for the requested row and pull out the individual strings that you want to display.  All the other decisions have already been made.

Answer (score 1):

It's a default behavior to show you empty rows in the end of the `TableView`, if your content does not fill up the screen. To remove those empty rows do the following in your `viewDidLoad` call:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

And to filter your `Array` for items, which really do have content, I'd recommend you using the `filter` method. An example for an `Array` which contains only `Strings`:

```
let filteredArray = contentArray.filter { data in

var data = contentArray[indexPath.row]
var documentFolder = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
var urlForPlayer: NSURL!

if var urlFromFolder: NSURL = documentFolder.first as? NSURL {
    urlForPlayer = urlFromFolder.URLByAppendingPathComponent(data)
}

println(urlForPlayer)

var player = AVPlayerItem(URL: urlForPlayer)
var nameSong: String!
var nameAlbum: String!
var nameArtistForCell: String!
var dataForImage: NSData!

var commonMetaData = player.asset.commonMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem]
for item in commonMetaData {
    if item.commonKey == "title" {
        nameSong = item.stringValue
    }
    if item.commonKey == "album" {
        nameAlbum = item.stringValue
    }
    if item.commonKey == "artist" {
        nameArtistForCell = item.stringValue
    }
    if item.commonKey == "artwork" {
        dataForImage = item.dataValue
    }
}

// only add this to my new array, if I have all available meta data information
return nameSong != nil && nameAlbum && nil && nameArtistForcell != nil && dataForImage && nil
}
```

You can read more about **Closure Expressions** [in the Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94).

Comment: This is if I use usual array, but I get data from [AVMetaDataItem] array. I made how you wrote but I got the same only without other rows.

Comment: An Array is an Array. You can always filter it. It doesn't matter what you filter. I do not have experience with the `AVFoundation` framework. Maybe there is a filter included there? Anyway, you can filter it yourself by using the code I posted. Of course this is only an example. As long as you return `true` in the end, the item will be included in the new Array

Answer (score 0):

The function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` return `contentArray.count` that means all songs of all artists.
But the function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` show metadata of the specific artist. Therefore, there are empty rows on tableview.

It is better to filter the songs of specific artist in `viewDidLoad` function and put them to `songOfArtistArray` (for example).
So, the function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` should return `songOfArtistArray.count`.